# html5 video functions enter/exit fullscreen

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to bind functions to `webkitRequestFullScreen()` and `webkitExitFullscreen();`? Meaning when I trigger fullscreen the video can play `$('#myVideo').get(0).play()` and on exit it will pause `$('#myVideo').get(0).pause()`

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10707091/3702797) can help

Comment: do you ONLY want to fire functions for Webkit? Or are you wanting a cross-browser option?