# Is there a way to detect when a browser exits full screen mode using javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-fullscreen

Is there a way to detect when a browser exits full screen mode using javascript?

Background info:
I am working on an HTML5 Player and have a button to enter full screen.
When in full screen mode, I want the toolbar (for the player) to be hidden.
Then when user exits full screen mode I want the toolbar to be visible again.
I am able to detect when the fullscreen button I added is clicked, and when escape key is pressed.
However, I am not able to determine when the browser message "Exit Full Screen" is clicked.

Problem:
I need to know how to add an event or somehow detect when a user clicks
"Exit Full Screen (Esc)" when in full screen mode so I can get the player to
show my toolbar. Adding an event to the escape key did not fix my problem.

Comment: Hey @ksol, in order for people to really help you I'd recommend making your questions readable (i.e. use newlines, punctation). Also, when putting code in your questions, use the proper code styling present in the text editor of Stackoverflow. Lastly, we need to see more code than what you posted.

Comment: I updated my question a bit. I don't need help with my code on making the toolbar visible, I just need to know how I can detect when the browser's message "Exit Full Screen (Esc)" is clicked (not when the user presses the escape key).

Comment: I think this has been already answered in another post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen)

Comment: if (document.addEventListener)
{
    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler, false);
}

function exitHandler()
{
    if (document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement !== null)
    {
        /* Run code on exit */
    }
}

Comment: I tried that code I just put above and it didn't work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when a page exits fullscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen)