# Capture ESC press not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the  HTML5 Full-Screen API and including some content in the page. I don't want to close the full screen mode on any key clicks like <kbd>ESC</kbd>. Or I want to load the page again on <kbd>ESC</kbd>. And I tried capturing the <kbd>ESC</kbd> by the following code,

But When I do pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> when full screen mode is active, the following function is not working. How can I disable <kbd>ESC</kbd> on full screen mode or do something on keydown the <kbd>ESC</kbd>?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    var charCode = e.charCode || e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (charCode == 27){
         alert("Escape is not allowed!");
         activateFullScreen(document.getElementById("myDiv"));
    }
});
});

function activateFullScreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullScreen) {
    element.requestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }
}

function myFunction() {
activateFullScreen(document.getElementById("myDiv"));
}
```

html:

```
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDiv"> Some content here </div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Things_your_users_want_to_know

Comment: You can’t stop people from leaving fullscreen. That would be a horrible security flaw.

Comment: @Ryan I was curious about that myself. Even if it was possible, overriding the defaults (i.e. hitting ESC) would be frustrating to me as a user.

Comment: @Ryan.. Okay. Say someone press ESC and window closes. Shall I open it again in another second? I tried `if (charCode == 27){` to capture that event. But this seems unreachable on `ESC`

Comment: The window’s not going to close; it’s going to leave fullscreen. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen for that event. If you have some permanent permission to fullscreen without prompting somehow, you can immediately reenter fullscreen from there.