# How to listen on exit fullscreen event in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have below code to enter fullscreen and listen on exist fullscreen event. This code works fine for `chrome`, `safari`, `edge`. But the `exitListener` is not called in firefox when exiting fullscreen mode. Does anyone know how to implement exit event listener in firefox?

```
const el = $('.mydiv')[0];
        const rfs =
            el.requestFullscreen ||
            el.webkitRequestFullScreen ||
            el.mozRequestFullScreen ||
            el.msRequestFullscreen;
        ['webkitfullscreenchange', 'mozfullscreenchange', 'fullscreenchange', 'msfullscreenchange'].forEach(
            eventName => $('.mydiv').bind(eventName, exitListener)
        );
        rfs.call(el, Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);

const exitListener = () => {
        const state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
        if (!state) {
           // fullscreen exit
        }
}
```

I have read the post `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen` but the solution there doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when a page exits fullscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen)

Comment: I have read that post before but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fullscreenchange` will fire on the document in Firefox when exiting, so you need to attach it there.

```js
const el = $('.mydiv')[0];
const rfs =
  el.requestFullscreen ||
  el.webkitRequestFullScreen ||
  el.mozRequestFullScreen ||
  el.msRequestFullscreen;
['webkitfullscreenchange', 'mozfullscreenchange', 'fullscreenchange', 'msfullscreenchange'].forEach(
  eventName => $(document).on(eventName, exitListener)
);
rfs.call(el, Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);

const exitListener = () => {
  const state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
  if (!state) {
    // fullscreen exit
  }
}
```

**[As a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7L6xu2o/)** since StackSnippet®'s iframe doesn't have the *allowfullscreen* attribute.