# How to detect when someone exits full screen using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display an element when user exits the fullscreen. How can i detect it. I am a beginner so please help me !

Comment: this should answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect when a page exits fullscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen)

Comment: similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen Good day!

Comment: can you please share the correct answer from these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen Please