# How do I check to exit from full screen with nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
'use client'

const  App = () => {
  const [isFScreen, setIsFScreen] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const down = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape"){
          setIsFScreen(false)
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("keydown", down)
  }, [])

  return(
    <div id="gameScreen">
     <span onClick={() => {
       setIsFScreen(!isFScreen)
       document.getElementById("gameScreen")?.requestFullscreen()}}>
         Full Screen
     </span>
    </div>
)}
```

When I press the ESC key once, it exits full screen but "setIsFScreen" does not become false. I have to press it twice to make it false. How can i solve this?

I was expecting the status to be false when it exited full screen.

Comment: Depends on if you actually want to write it yourself but why don't you just use already existing recipes for a `useFullscreen` Hook or a library instead ?

Comment: actually im using nextjs, how can I do it with nextjs?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect when a page exits fullscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706070/how-to-detect-when-a-page-exits-fullscreen)

Comment: naah, it didn't work for me, i still haven't found a way @DeanVanGreunen

Comment: [`document.exitFullscreen()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/exitFullscreen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  const [isFScreen, setFullScreen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleFullScreenChange() {
      if (document.fullscreenElement) {
        setFullScreen(true);
      } else {
        setFullScreen(false);
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', handleFullScreenChange);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('fullscreenchange', handleFullScreenChange);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleEscKeyPress(event:any) {
      if (event.key === 'Escape') {
        exitFullScreen();
      }
    }

    if (isFScreen) {
      window.addEventListener('keydown', handleEscKeyPress);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEscKeyPress);
    }

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEscKeyPress);
    };
  }, [isFScreen]);

  const enterFullScreen = () => {
    if (document.getElementById("gameScreen")?.requestFullscreen) {
      document.getElementById("gameScreen")?.requestFullscreen();
    }
  };

  const exitFullScreen = () => {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    }
  };
```

> I solved this problem with ChatGPT. THANKS CHATGPT!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just use the listen events for fulllscreen

```
const  App = () => {
  const [isFScreen, setIsFScreen] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const exitHandler= (e:any) => {
       setIsFScreen(false);
    }

    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
  }, [])

  return(
    <div id="gameScreen">
     <span onClick={() => {
       setIsFScreen(!isFScreen)
       document.getElementById("gameScreen")?.requestFullscreen()}}>
         Full Screen
     </span>
    </div>
)}
```

> Supports Opera, Safari, Chrome with webkit, Firefox/Gecko with moz, IE 11 with MSFullScreenChange, and will support the actual spec with fullscreenchange once it's been successfully implemented in all of the browsers. Obviously, Fullscreen API is only supported in the modern browsers, so I did not provide attachEvent fallbacks for older versions of IE.