# How to detect 'going into' fullscreen mode? - Fullscreen Web API

Tags: javascript, fullscreen, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the [Fullscreen Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode).

```
  function goFullscreen(){

     var elem =  document.body;
     if (elem.requestFullscreen)  elem.requestFullscreen();
     else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
     else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(); 

     var fullscreenElement = document.mozFullScreenElement;   
     if(fullscreenElement){
     /** some changes to the page **/
     }     
   }
```

And I used the [`document.mozFullScreenElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.mozFullScreenElement) to check whether the page is fullscreen or not.

But, that check works only when the page is ALREADY fullscreen not when it *goes* fullscreen (that is when user clicks "Allow"). So, Is there any hack for this?

Comment: Does this answer help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617963/how-to-detect-if-user-has-enabled-full-screen-in-browser  ?

Comment: In here : http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen , David walsh mentiones that `The fullscreenchange event lets us know when we go to/from fullscreen mode` . You can detect that using `var fullscreenElement = document.fullscreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement;
var fullscreenEnabled = document.fullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullScreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled;`

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, in the question itself I had mentioned that I am using the `document.mozFullScreenElement` which works only when the page is ALREADY in the fullscreen mode!

Answer (score 1):

Use this if statement cross browser to detect if we're not currently in full screen mode:

```
            if (
                !document.isFullScreen &&
                !document.fullscreenElement &&
                !document.webkitFullscreenElement &&
                !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
                !document.msFullscreenElement
            )
            { // make full screen }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a really good post on this http://xme.im/display-fullscreen-website-using-javascript which has a good overview of support in different browsers.  Also goes on to suggest some events that can be used.

If that doesn't work I suppose a (nasty-ish) hack would be introducing an setInterval poll that checks for fullscreen and if true fires a custom event and clears the interval?

EDIT...

I had a play around with the above code in the article and agree it doesn't solve the issue.  Also size based detection of whether in full screen mode behaves unpredictably in some cases.

Overall with browser behaviour it seems that it is considered "full screen" the moment it goes full screen (in the case of Chrome, this is before the user clicks Allow).  The following code allowed me to detect this with no delays/intervals necessary, but since the user can still exit full screen mode at any time (via Deny or browser controls) you'd still have to tear down any page changes you made on entering full screen.  I think since there are no events we have to treat Deny the same as a normal exit. Code below is webkit only, but could easily be adapted with alt prefixes/pseudo classes.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        html, body { height : 100%; width : 100%; }
    </style>        
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
            var isFullScreen = $("body:-webkit-full-screen").length;
            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = (isFullScreen)? "I am full screen" : "I am NOT full screen";          
        }, false);

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Hello
    <div id="status"></div>
    <button onclick="document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen()">&nbsp;Request FullScreen&nbsp;</button>       
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the post, am afraid I couldn't find anything useful regarding the question, except for some future proposals & yea I thought of intervals too but was a bit hesitant, thought someone else might come up with something better here :). +1 for interval!

Comment: nope, the code is not working for me I tweaked the prefixes,pseudoclass, and the function to match the browser, but it didnt :(

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do those checks like you did, but instead going fullscreen, call the function which is doing some changes on the page, and after that going to full screen:

so as example:

```
 function goFullscreen(){
   var elem =  document.body;
   if (elem.requestFullscreen) 
    changeContent("requestFullscreen")
   else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) 
    changeContent("mozRequestFullScreen")
   else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) 
    changeContent("webkitRequestFullscreen")
 }

 function changeContent(fullScreenType) {
   var elem =  document.body;
   /** some changes to the page, **/

    /** after those changes, do the check and go fullscreen **/
   if (fullScreenType == "requestFullscreen")
    elem.requestFullscreen();
   else if (fullScreenType == "mozRequestFullscreen")
    elem.mozRequestFullscreen();
   else if (fullScreenType == "webkitRequestFullscreen")
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();

 }
```

Comment: and what will happen when the user had denied the fullscreen request? Then the changes would have already had happened, which they shouldn't have!

Comment: maybe you can undo the changes if the page isn't in fullscreen mode anymore? Because if you do the request, you are already in fullscreen mode before the allow/deny is possible (like you already said). There's also something as "mozfullscreenerror", but I don't know if this event occurs when the user clicks the deny button

Comment: fullscreen can't occur before allow/deny! and thanks for suggesting _mozfullscreenerror_, but that is an event that occurs when the element requesting fullscreen doesn't support fullscreen.

Comment: I saw some demos online, for example here: http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/fullscreen.html
and if I click on toggle Full Screen, I'm already in fullscreen mode before I can allow (or close) the full screen...

Comment: I get what you mean, It does _appear_ fullscreen, but honestly it doesn't get registered as a fullscreen coz when I tried to check/test for fullscreen, it didn't pass! and also there is still the question of what I will do when the user clicks _deny_. PS: I have literally tried the code you have suggested in your answer and like I said the change is there even when the user clicks _deny_ :( and the check for fullscreen always return false (both during _allow_ && _deny_)

Comment: Yes, after your first comment I already realised it's always executing, even if the user clicks deny. My only idea now is, undo the changes when exiting fullscreen mode.. But I don't think you want to do that either..
Hopefully someone else can help you further with this problem.