# How do you cause a style change on exiting fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button that toggles fullscreen and toggles some classes for div tags at the same time. The problem is that when the user presses escape, fullscreen closes, but the toggled classes do not toggle. Can someone provide a way to toggle a class on canceling fullscreen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if user has enabled full screen in browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617963/how-to-detect-if-user-has-enabled-full-screen-in-browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
$(window).resize(toggleStyles);
function toggleStyles(e) {
    if(window.innerWidth >= screen.width && window.innerHeight >= screen.height) {
        ... change styles here ...
    }
}
```

Also, if you are not useing jQuery this should do that same thing

```
window.addEventListener('resize', toggleStyles);
```