# How to check if the document is not in fullScreen mode using javascript or react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to check if the screen is in not in fullscreenmode and render a component?

I have tried using

```
{!window.FullScreen && 
    <ChildComponent/>}
```

But this doesnt seem to work. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How to detect if user has enabled full screen in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617963/how-to-detect-if-user-has-enabled-full-screen-in-browser)

As for taking a quick glance myself you should try the answer provided there.